# Getting TypeError must be str not bytes with echo command

Tags: python-3.x

Am upgrading to py3 and have py2 compatible code which is now throwing an error of **TypeError: must be str, not bytes**

In the script its sending a shell echo command with an encoded string.

```
"echo \"" + base64.b64encode(b'Hello World') + "\" | base64 -d"
```

How can I modify the above to make it pass?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the strings to bytes as well and then decode them:

```py
bytes_string = b"echo \"" + base64.b64encode(b'Hello World') + b"\" | base64 -d"
print(bytes_string.decode('utf-8'))

>>> echo "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=" | base64 -d
```

Comment: Hi, I tried above code but it gives me AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'string_decode'

Comment: The underscore is between bytes and string not string and decode